# Prime spacing with mathcal font

Tags: horizontal-alignment, mathcal

Compare the following:

Here is the code and an image:

```
\begin{align}
    V'(t) &= 0 \\
    \mathcal{V}'(t) &= 0
\end{align}
```

The first has a regular 'V'. The second uses `mathcal`.

[image]

On my system at least, the spacing between the letter and the prime is much less in the `mathcal` case.
Is this supposed to be the case? Is there a way to adjust it?

Comment: To me the spacing looks pretty much the same (i.e. the distance from the right boundary of `V` to the left boundary of `'`, see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlMG0.png)).

Comment: I was wondering about that. I guess it's aligning based on the surrounding boxes. But because the left-most point of the prime is in line with the right-most point of the mathcal V, it appears closer.

Comment: You can always insert manual kerning, e.g. `\mathcal{V}\mkern1mu'(t)`.

Comment: Regarding your note in the question, see [Why doesn't maths render as maths?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/why-doesnt-maths-render-as-maths).

Comment: note that tex has no information about the shape of any character, it only has the font metrics so every character is a rectangular box of four lengths (height, width, depth, italic correction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following example. Furthermore, if space is not your interest, change the number in the new command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand*{\myprime}{^{\mkern 2mu \prime}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
V'(t) &= 0 \\
\mathcal{V}\myprime(t) &= 0
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

It gives

[image]